# How to make a variable behave as an object?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I make a variable behave like a function/object. I would like to implement something similar to [Jasmine Matchers](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matchers)

```
describe("The 'toBe' matcher compares with ===", function() {
  it("and has a positive case", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });


  it("and can have a negative case", function() {
    expect(false).not.toBe(true);
  });
});
```

How can I implement something like `not.toBe()`?

Comment: one version of `toBe` on `expect`, another on `not`.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just returning an object that looks a bit like this:

```
{
    not : {
        toBe : function () {}
    },
    toBe : function () {}
}
```

So, the object returns basically has two members - the object `not` and the function `toBe`. The object `not` has one member - another function called `toBe`.

A simple implementation of the expect function:

```
function expect (var) {
    return {
        toBe : function (var2) {
            if (var != var2) {
                throw new Error("not to be");
            }
        },
        not : {
            toBe : function (var2) {
                if (var == var2) {
                    throw new Error("not NOT to be");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `expect` function above will throw error if the variable inspected is not what it expects:

```
expect(false).toBe(false);
expect(false).not.toBe(true);
expect(false).toBe(true); // error
expect(false).not.toBe(false); // error
```

---

Note: This is just syntax sugar to make the code "pretty". The same logic can be implemented just by using appropriate function names:

```
function expect (var) {
    return {
        toBe : function (var2) {
            if (var != var2) {
                throw new Error("not to be");
            }
        },
        not_ToBe : function (var2) {
            if (var == var2) {
                throw new Error("not NOT to be");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is simpler but maybe not as pretty:

```
expect(false).toBe(false);
expect(false).not_toBe(true);
expect(false).toBe(true); // error
expect(false).not_toBe(false); // error
```

Comment: I don't see how the two functions called `toBe` can be considered duplicate since they do opposite things: the first toBe checks if they're not equal. The second toBe checks if they're equal.

Comment: This is basically the same logic as if you had two functions called `toBe` and `notToBe`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a object in javascript. 
Here is a example of a object with the function "Hallo".

```
var testObj = {
    Hallo: function() {alert("Hallo");}
};
```

You can call it with:

```
testObj.Hallo();
```

And have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Ugh, w3schools is the worst resource ever. Don't link to that please.